# 500 Internal Server Error on a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, internal-server-error

I've created a Facebook page (with WordPress) but I can't get it to work in Facebook.

The original page is working fine at: (just add the https to see the SSL version)

```
http://copywriting.com/fb/fanpage/pueblito-reserve/
```

However, when I load it into Facebook, the SSL version works fine, but the regular http version gives back a 500 Internal Server Error.

Regular FB tab (with the 500 error):  (add the https and it works fine)

```
 http://www.facebook.com/PueblitoEscondido/app_382773098443040
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

> How can this be solved?

By looking into your server’s logfiles to see what *caused* this error …